# How to degub sass on iPhone with sencha touch

Tags: ios, css, extjs, sencha-touch, ios-simulator

I have changed the sass file in sencha and compiled it
Cleared iPhone simulator, cleaned the project

Nothing helps, in the browser I can see that the new styles were applied, however in the iPhone simulator and iPhone itself they haven't

So basically this is the smallest changed I wanted to try:

from: `.x-desktop .x-title .x-innerhtml{padding: 0;padding:0;color:fff;}`

to: `.x-desktop .x-title .x-innerhtml{padding: 0;padding:0;color:`**#52A5D6**`;}`

So my question is:

1. Why could cause this issue? **Solved:** if you look at the first class it belongs to x-desktop...
2. How to debug the sass if the styles have been transferred to the devise and applied?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Safari's Web Inspector to inspect your application while running in the simulator, or while running on a connected iOS device. To do this, first open up Safari and go to Preferences -> Advanced, and check the "Show Develop menu in menu bar" checkbox.

[image: Enabling the Web Inspector]

After this, launch your application in either the simulator or a connected device, then bring Safari to focus. Click on the "Develop" menu, and then either "iPhone Simulator" or the name of your device. You will see the page listed in the next menu.

[image: Opening the Web Inspector for the simulator]

From here, after navigating to the page, you can use the Web Inspector to inspect the page like you would if it were in the webpage.

[image: Inspecting a page]